# C# check html tag inside text with regex

Tags: c#, regex

This is my html:

```
<div class="bla">
followers
<a href="">followers count </a>
</div>
```

What i want is that, if `<div class="bla" />` inside text equals followers get next a tag inside text(followers count). I know this would be easy with htmlagilitypack but in this case can't use it. How to do it with regex?

Comment: You want to parse HTML with regex?

Comment: Yes i can't use htmlagilitypack  in this case

Comment: [<div class=\"bla\">](http://regexr.com/3cf5t)

Comment: But why regex? If you can't use HtmlAgilityPack then there are other packages designed for this purpose.

Comment: I am parsing facebook, and content is inside scripts and commented. only regex see it

Comment: What do you mean only regex can see it? Can you give a concrete example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
    var mtch = Regex.Match(input, 
"<div class[ ]?=[ ]?\"bla[^\"]*\"[ ]?>(?<groupName>[\\w\\W]+</div>");
    if (mtch.Groups["groupName"].Value.ToLower().Contains("followers"))
    {
        //do your stuff
    }
```